# how to disable pointer events but allow browser menu (open image & save image) with only css?

Tags: javascript, css

```js
let img = document.getElementById("img");
img.addEventListener("click" , function handleClick() {

      if  (img.style.width = "60%") {
  img.style.opacity = "0.5";
      }
});
```

```css
.img { 
  width: 60%;
  cursor: pointer;
/*   pointer-events: none;  */
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/3437/3403778548_15f48ab99e_b.jpg" class="img" id="img">
</body>
</html>
```

```
 pointer-events:none;
```

but allow browser menu (open image in a new tab or save image as).

If not possible with only CSS, then how to get browser width as a condition to disable click event in specific width with JavaScript, but again allow browser menu (open image in a new tab or save image as)?

it's like disable click for the code only but not for the browser menu options.

Comment: Some more context is necessary here. You can disable `pointer-events` on your whole page and just enable it for images if you want to `img { pointer-events: all; }`?

Comment: show a working snippet

Comment: its quiet unclear what you want to achieve, you want to set properties on `img` click but at the same time you want to use `pointer-events: none`  for only some `width` of the image ?

Comment: disable the css click but don't remove option from browser to save image or open it in a new tab.

Comment: what is the reason to disable the click in img ?

Comment: Viewport width goes mobile. For example 975px